# jQuery replace all instances of $0 on a page

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a table of products in a cart. Wherever the price is set as $0 I want to change it to TBC.
I have used code as follows:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var replacedAmount = jQuery('body').html().replace('$0','TBC');
        jQuery('body').html(replacedAmount);
    });
```

I'm thinking there's some regex thing needed because of the $ but /$/ doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: it is not at all a good idea to change the entire html of the page since any event/data attached prior to this will get lost because of this... but other solution will be very costly as you will have to iterate through all the text nodes

Comment: Why don't you do this serverside?

Comment: Why don't you select the table's cells instead of entire HTML content of the body element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var replacedAmount = jQuery('body').html().replace(/\$0/g,'TBC');
```

or

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('body').html(function(_,old_html){
        return old_html.replace(/\$0/g, 'TBC');
    });
});
```

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml)

It's not a good idea to change the entire html of body.

Instead you can replace html of that particular div/span/p etc. where you know `$0` appears

you can also do as you say it's in table

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('table').html(function(_,old_html){
        return old_html.replace(/\$0/g, 'TBC');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the global flag:

```
var replacedAmount = jQuery('body').html().replace(/\$0/g,'TBC');
```

See also:
[More info on JS regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

However, this is probably not the best approach. If you know the specific elements, for example you mention a table, select those elements explicitly and do the replacement there, rather than on the entire page's html.